# inotify file write completion - golang & Postfix

Tags: go, postfix-mta, inotify

I'm using Postfix on a server to receive emails.
When an email is received I want to trigger some golang code.
I'm using the `inotify` package, and am monitoring the `Maildir/new` folder for new incoming emails.

I'm monitoring only the `IN_CLOSE_WRITE` event on the folder, but I see it's never being triggered. Only `IN_CREATE` events are being triggered.

I assume that as I'm monitoring the folder, and not the file, it sees just the create file events (as they effect the folder), not what happens later to the file (close write).

However I don't know the name of the file in advance, it's a temp file being created by Postfix outside of my control, and I don't want just to sleep for let's say 1 second as it may take longer for Postfix to finish writing, and then on the other hand if I try to set up a watch quickly on that file I may be on a race condition with Postfix, as it may finish writing the email much faster that I would have even established the initial watch, and I would not be able to distinguish between file created, written and closed, and write in progress, as events are not being triggered during that time.

How would you have elegantly resolved this issue?
I don't want to sleep, as it's not elegant and I cannot know for sure for how long, and I want it to be as short as possible, and I don't want to be in any race condition with Postfix.

Comment: Are you listening to IN_MOVED_TO event too?

Comment: you probably want to replace the entire file anyway, in order to prevent race conditions. Write first a temp file and once you have written it all, you mv it over the old file. You proably need to rewatch file, on delete event.

Comment: @Pablo I'm watching all the events, only IN_CREATE events are being fired.

Comment: @tripleee that can be a good direction if I don't find an easier path. I have really minimal interactions with Postfix, so I prefer not to go that way, unless I have no other choice. I prefer this to be resolved on the inotify level if possible.

Answer (score 2):

I believe Postfix easily lets you hook into the actual delivery event. Look at how Procmail does it, or even just create a Procmail rule to run your script when something is delivered.

In very brief, in your `.procmailrc`, put

```
:0c
| /path/to/your/binary
```

to pipe a copy of each incoming message to your binary.

Comment: this is a much more practical solution, @Vitaliy.

Answer (score 0):

OK, to anyone that encounters this I understand what's going on :)
The whole sequence of events is:

```
"/home/server/Maildir/tmp/1702916546.P795095.server": 0x100 == IN_CREATE
"/home/server/Maildir/tmp/1702916546.P795095.server": 0x20 == IN_OPEN
"/home/server/Maildir/tmp/1702916546.P795095.server": 0x2 == IN_MODIFY
"/home/server/Maildir/tmp/1702916546.P795095.server": 0x8 == IN_CLOSE_WRITE
"/home/server/Maildir/new/1702916546.V802I24257M499995.server": 0x100 == IN_CREATE
"/home/server/Maildir/tmp/1702916546.P795095.server": 0x200 == IN_DELETE
```

So as you can see, the email file is of course being created in the tmp dir first, where the long seeked for IN_CLOSE_WRITE is actually being triggered, and after the file is completely written, it is being moved to the new directory, and deleted from the tmp directory.
That's why the new directory only sees the IN_CREATE.

So what happens here is simply an mv from one dir to another, in the same filesystem, so it seems safe to just monitor the new dir for IN_CREATE  events.

@triplee's approach also looks great when the binary needs to be triggered from clean - i.e the binary is completely independent, there is no logic that runs before the trigger. In my case it was more convenient to stay in the context of the server.

Comment: I don't understand "be triggered from clean"; could you rephrase that?